# use different layout not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

for my download action I want to use a layout I created pdf.ctp

here is my action in controller

```
function download($id = null) {
        $this->layout = 'pdf'; 
        // Include Component
        App::import('Component', 'Pdf');
        // Make instance
        $Pdf = new PdfComponent();
        // Invoice name (output name)
        $Pdf->filename = 'contract'; // Without .pdf
        // You can use download or browser here
        $Pdf->output = 'download';
        $Pdf->init();
        // Render the view
        $Pdf->process(Router::url('/', true) . 'pv/pdf_contract/');
        $this->render(false);
    }
```

but its still using default layout.
not sure why
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to but $this->layout=false in the referencing method and not in actual download method.
thanks